# Create top 12 with a minimum and maximum of each option (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of 20 athletes with different positions, for the creation of a team lineup the players cannot all be in the same position, we cannot have 12 `atacante` for example, and we cannot have 0 `atacante` too, so we have a minimum and a maximum of athletes for each position, I need to be able to create a list with 12 athletes but there is a minimum and a maximum for each position (`Técnico`, `Goleiro`, `Zagueiro`, `Lateral`, `Meia` and `Atacante`).

I tried to use:
`=QUERY({FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H2)*((D2:D21>=I2)*(D2:D21<=J2)));FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H3)*((D2:D21>=I3)*(D2:D21<=J3)));FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H4)*((D2:D21>=I4)*(D2:D21<=J4)));FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H5)*((D2:D21>=I5)*(D2:D21<=J5)));FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H6)*((D2:D21>=I6)*(D2:D21<=J6)));FILTER(C2:E21,(D2:D21=H7)*((D2:D21>=I7)*(D2:D21<=J7)))},"Limit 12")` and limit the **maximum** and **minimum** of each option but I **couldn't get it to be limited** to exactly the first 12 on the list.

TOP 20:
[image]

Minimum and Maximum of each position:
[image]

Expected Result:
[image]

LINK TO SPREADSHEET:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u4G5lwN-jFcnrl-40SwgmMTRup_4r469p6W4OD5ngfg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've built on the essential work by MattKing, and come up with the following variation - see GK.Help in your sheet:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(UNIQUE(
  {iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A=1 and G>0"),{"","","","","","","",""});
   iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A=2 and G=2"),{"","","","","","","",""});
   iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A=3 and G=3"),{"","","","","","","",""});
   QUERY({iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I2&"' order by A limit "&K2-1),{"","","","","","","",""});
          iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I3&"' order by A limit "&K3-1),{"","","","","","","",""});
          iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I4&"' order by A limit "&K4-1),{"","","","","","","",""});
          iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I5&"' order by A limit "&K5-1),{"","","","","","","",""});
          iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I6&"' order by A limit "&K6-1),{"","","","","","","",""});
          iferror(QUERY(A2:H,"where A>1 and D='"&I7&"' order by A limit "&K7-1),{"","","","","","","",""})},
     "order by Col2 ")}),
     "where Col1>0 limit " & 12),
     "select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col2 order by Col4,Col2")
```

Like Matt, and using stacked queries, I take the first player at each position. But I then also take the 2nd player at each position which has a minimum of 2, then add the 3rd player at each position which has a minimum of 3.  This could be continued as required.

Next, we query for all players in positions which are below their max, taken in order by their overall ranking.  We then use `UNIQUE` to remove any possible duplicate selections.  We then use one `QUERY` to select the first 12 players from this combined list, which **is not yet in ranking order** - otherwise we might drop some players from a position with a MIN of 3, for example. Lastly, we sort these 12 players by position and ranking.  Note the 12 could be accessed as a variable, if desired.

The many blank values are the `IFERROR` values, to avoid the stacked queries failing due to any empty query results.
For clarity, I've sorted by position, then by ranking, but this can be changed to ranking first.

Note that I added the possibility of having a MIN of zero, and I check each position for MIN and MAX.  I also used a helper column, G, to add the MIN for that position to each data record.  I think that this could be done without the helper column, if necessary - let me know.

Let me know if this seems to work for you.

[image]

Comment: I will do some tests but so far it worked perfectly, I will study hard to understand what you produced, it will be of immense use for my project! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think i understand the question.  Thanks for the sheet link.  You'll find my solution on the MK.Help tab.

This stacked query should do it.  The first query just picks the top player at each position, then the second stack of queries stacks the remaining players and orders them by the overall position, limiting each position to the max minus 1. And limiting the overall output to 6 since you already have your first 6 from the "best" players query.

```
=QUERY({QUERY(A2:F,"where A=1");QUERY({QUERY(A2:F,"where A>1 and D='"&H4&"' order by A limit "&J4-1);QUERY(A2:F,"where A>1 and D='"&H5&"' order by A limit "&J5-1);QUERY(A2:F,"where A>1 and D='"&H6&"' order by A limit "&J6-1);QUERY(A2:F,"where A>1 and D='"&H7&"' order by A limit "&J7-1)},"order by Col2 limit 6")},"order by Col4,Col1")
```

Comment: Mate, when I updated the player data I found a fault, the number of "Meia" was below the minimum. Could you help me with this adjustment?

Comment: I’d like to apologize for removing the tag that your answer solved the problem. Because unfortunately it didn't work out when the data changed, I updated the question to show that the problem persists.